# Access e excel - carregar parâmetros

Tags: microsoft-excel, parâmetros, microsoft-access

é possível usar uma tabela do excel como parâmetros para consultas do access?
Atualmente tenho 4 arquivos access para realizar o mesmo processo, mas com filtros diferentes (usei 4 arquivos para deixar organizado). Os filtros são basicamente DATA INÍCIO, DATA FIM e um campo DESCRIÇÃO. Gostaria de deixar essas informações no excel e deixar o access só para processar.

Se não for possível essa solução, é possível carregar vários parâmetros de uma vez nas consultas do access? Teria o mesmo efeito prático, pois carregaria os parâmetros de cada processo antes da execução.

Comment: A sua pergunta parece me mais indicada para o [Super User](https://superuser.com/) uma vez que não parece abranger nada de programação

Comment: entendo, mas se a única solução for via macro, terá código envolvido, por isso postei aqui

Comment: É possível sim, inclusive, seria possível também simplesmente criar um arquivo de configuração, **txt** mesmo, ao invés de um Excel.

Comment: Mas porque os 4 arquivos Access separados?

Comment: @Marco, e como criaria esse TXT para configuração? Essa é minha dúvida. Hoje, eu mantenho em 4 arquivos separados pois são processos diferentes, que usam as mesmas bases. Se colocar todos juntos ficaria impossível de organizar

Comment: @fhbeltrami creio que interpretei mal o seu problema. Você tem 4 cópias de um arquivo Access com as mesmas tabelas e dados, mas cada uma tem um consulta pesquisando diferentes valores?

Comment: Conseguiria exemplificar um pouco melhor onde ficam os registros e o que exatamente você está utilizando do Access? (ex.: formulário, consulta, relatório, tabela)